# SQL Server Clustered Index Non Unique Without primary key

Tags: sql-server, indexing, non-clustered-index

I have an index on my table (SQL Server 2016 - enterprise edition). It seems it is created without a primary key (so just including all the columns). Whenever I try to show the create statement it gives me an error saying that it cannot create a index without primary key (but it is already there).

Does anyone know how a non clustered index can be created on a table, including ALL the columns but without using a primary key?

Comment: Why would you create an index on **all columns** of a table!?!? What did you think this will do for you?? Makes no sense at all to me .....

Comment: What is your table definition, what is the index creation statement? Indexes are allowed on any table, whether they have keys or not. Are you using the most recent version of Management Studio, compatible with SQL Server 2016?

Comment: The intend was to create a columnstore index. I thought one was created (the performance was excellent).. But apprently it didnt create a columnstore index but a normal index which includes all columns. Perhaps this is a bug in SQL Server that it doesn't display it as Columnstore index in that specific version (normally it indicates that it is a columnstore index).

Comment: You are conflating SQL Server (the engine) with SQL Server Management Studio (a tool for managing SQL Server with a GUI). The distinction matters. The most recent version of Management Studio, including SQL Server 2017 support, is [distributed separately](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). I have experienced no problems creating columnstore indexes or distinguishing them from regular indexes. For creating objects, however, nothing beats writing the command yourself (`CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX`), as this leaves no room for surprise.